# How to set portrait mode with libGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've created a game, and it is OK in desktop mode, but when i launch it on my S3, it goes in landscape mode, how can i change it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can set the screen orientation in the AndroidManifest.   android:screenOrientation="landscape"or your desired orientation. But you should provide more context.

Comment: i wanted to do so, but i'm using the 1.0 version of libgdx in android studio and there isn't any android manifest...

Comment: Of course there is, check the Android project. It is being generated by both the old and the new setup UIs.

Comment: sorry, that was my error, i'm new to the android studio and i was using the packages view instead of the project view

Answer (score 28):

[image]

android:screenOrientation:

- landscape
- portrait
- unspecified
- behind
- reverseLandscape
- reversePortrait
- sensorLandscape
- sensorPortrait

For more information you can visit: [Android Activity Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at the [`<activity>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). You can set the orientation as:

```
android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                     "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```