# Should I rotate background or rotate Orthographic camera?

Tags: libgdx

I'm developing a game with vertical screen orientation. Default of Libgdx screen is horizontal orientation. So I don't know should I rotate the background (texture/sprite) or I rotate camera 90 degrees, which solution is easy to develop later?

Comment: If the whole game should be in vertical ("portrait") orientation for android, you should change the orientation in the manifest file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402717/how-to-set-portrait-mode-with-libgdx). If you want a game with portrait-orientation on desktop, you should probably rotate the camera, but i don't guess thats what you want. If you instead only want to rotate the background, rotate the background `Texture` only.

Comment: thanks so much, manifest file is OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rotate anything.
Go to the Android subproject, open the AndroidManifest.xml file and change (or add) the "android:screenOrientation" attribute of the "activity" XML tag to "portrait".

Rotating the content would cause problem in many cases (default text direction, virtual keyboard appearence...).

Rada